# How can I increase the size of the pinned jump list in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, taskbar, jumplist

I use Notepad++ for a bunch of text files.  I like to pin my frequently used text files to the Notepad++ icon on the taskbar.  There seems to be a limit of 18 items visible.  I can pin more than 18 files but I can't see them.  I have plenty of screen real estate so the jumplist/pinned list could be a lot taller.  How can I increase the size of the "Pinned" portion of the jump list in Windows 7?

Note that I am NOT talking about the increasing the size of the "recent" portion of the jump list (I have that set to zero).  I can find plenty of hits on adjusting the size of that, but nothing on adjusting the size of the "Pinned" list.

Comment: Since nothing much returns in a Google search "change size of pinned jump list", your chances are slim in finding an answer soon. Great question.

Comment: Scroll down to the answer "Works in Windows 10" for the instructions on how to do this in Windows 10.  The reg entry specifies more room for either pinned or recent entries to be displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google doesn't seem to have anything on increasing the pinned section, but [Jumplist Launcher](http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/) could possibly get the result you're looking for, albeit with a bit more work. You'd have to add all of the files you want via the program, but the end result would appear be similar to pinning them all.

Comment: Jumplist Launcher looked intriguing but unfortunately it too seems to be subject to the mysterious 18 item limit.  There's an option to change the maximum jumplist size, but, at least on my Win7 box, it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually JumpList Launcher seems to work after all, and even better than advertised.  Run JumpList Launcher.  Increase the "Max. Jumplist-Items".  Hit Save.  Reboot your computer.  Now ALL pinned lists (not just those in JumpList Launcher) have that new size.  Including the start menu, which looks a little weird when it's super tall, but whatever.  Good enough.

Comment: FYI, as of 2021 June, the link provided for Jumplist Launcher is no longer valid.

Answer (score 43):

1. Right click on the Windows orb/start button and click **Properties**.
2. Click the **Start Menu** tab (if not already selected).
3. Click **Customize...**
   [image]
4. Set **Number of recent programs to display** and **Number of recent items to display in Jump Lists** to to something like 20.
   [image]

This also makes your start menu super tall, allows you to add more pinned programs to your start menu and more pinned programs to your pinned programs jump lists.

You don't need the jumplist launcher to do that.

I was wishing that when the limit was reached it would become a scrollable jump list like they do when you click all programs on the start menu. That would be ideal! Does the jumplist launcher do that?

Comment: This is the correct answer.  No hacks necessary.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.

Comment: +1, and I wonder why this is not the accepted answer

Comment: -1; This is a wrong answer. The OP asks for increasing pinned items on the **taskbar**, your method increases the pinned items in the **start menu**.

Comment: @hkBattousai : He asked about the **pinned items** list of the pinned taskbar icon. This is the list you get by right-clicking the icon, and is the same as the one you get from the start menu jumplists, so the solution is correct.

Comment: This works almost the same for Windows 8 as well. Just type 'taskbar' in the homescreen and under settings you will then find a settings program which you can use to change the number of pinned items.

Answer (score 15):

Browse to the following key in the registry editor:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ApplicationDestinations\MaxEntries
```

Change the decimal value of Max entries to whatever you like (the default is 17).

Comment: Not sure what Jumplist Launcher is, but this worked great for me, thanks!

Comment: This works very well, but after a reboot, my experience is that it always resets to 8 on Win7.  Any way to resolve that quirk?

Answer (score 9):

I was just doing this in Windows 8.1 and thought I'd add an answer to show the differences in that OS:

1. Right Click on the **taskbar** and go into **properties**.
2. Go to the **Jump Lists** tab.
3. Change the **number of recent items to display in Jump Lists** to a suitable number, the maximum is 60:

   [image: illustration of how to change jump lists]
4. Click OK

The recent items and pinned items share the space, so the number you set is a total across both types of item.  If you set it too high, then it will go off the top of your screen - with a 1200px vertical, I can fit about 45 items in a full-height jump list.

Comment: No points for the hand-drawn circle? SU, you disappoint!

Answer (score 7):

**Works in Windows 10**

To change quantity of Jump List items, open RegEdit and navigate to:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
Click on Advanced key. On menu, click `Edit > New > DWORD (32 bit) Value`.
Name it: `JumpListItems_Maximum`
Right click it, select Modify and set Hexadecimal Value to what you want. This takes immediate effect. No need to reboot system. Also works when those `Jump Lists` and `Start Menu` tabs are missing from `Taskbar and Start Menu Properties` window. :)

**Edit**:

I observed that jump lists open after a lot of delay if you set the jump list size to large number. In my case this occurred when I kept it to 30. So ended up reducing it to 15.

Comment: oh Yes, works perfekt! Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there's an [optional update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607576) to the jump list that allows for more than 999 items, though who would ever want 1,000 items in their list is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

It could set the jump list like real high and leave recent programs at 8 as the default or even set it to 0 if it has its jumplist set to all the programs it recently uses anyway. That's sort of the idea of recent applications.

So it could set recent to 0 even and other to twice the amount showing.

Comment: sounds to me as if you just need to go down by the clock and get the menu and pick toolbar and you can drag your shortcuts to it and ;then when click down on it it pops up a menu of your 'programs ya want to get to

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7

Check "Use small icons" in "Taskbar" tab.

[image]