# Windows 7 / Star Menu item list size

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, start-menu

Is it possible on Windows 7 to adjust the size of the item list in Start Menu? I would like to know if it is possible to make it hold more items. I am attaching the following image of the list I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the Windows orb/start button and click **Properties**.
2. Click the **Start Menu** tab (if not already selected).
3. Click **Customize...**

   [image]
4. Set **Number of recent programs to display** to something like 20.

   [image]

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/311429/23133)

Comment: Hi, Techie007. Thanks for the quick reply. It did somewhat helped by lengthening the list but is there any option to change the list item sizes themselves, and possibly without having to enable "Store and display recently opened..." options under "Start Menu->Privacy"?

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround: disabling "Store and display recently opened programs(...)" and "Store and display recently opened items(...)" will not reset the custom values of "Number of recent programs(...)" and "Number of recent items(...)". It will render the values greyed out with a value of 0. The system reboot and user log off do NOT reset the changes.