# How to prevent a Windows 7 registry setting from always getting reset to the default on reboot?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry, taskbar, jumplist

Hopefully this question will be asking the correct question, and not be an infamous "XY" problem question.  The challenge is that "X" has already been asked and answered, but that answer results in question "X2", which is this question.

With that in mind, the overall goal is to allow more pinned items in the ***static*** Jump Lists for Windows 7 taskbar icons.  (Not ***recent*** items, but ***static*** items!)  [This question asks exactly that question](https://superuser.com/questions/200153/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-the-pinned-jump-list-in-windows-7/), and after performing some research, I think [this is likely the correct answer](https://superuser.com/a/262388/380110).

The answer involves changing the value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ApplicationDestinations\MaxEntries` to whatever maximum you want.  Easy peasy.  It works great and doesn't even require the shell to be reloaded (or a reboot).

The issue I found, however, is that after a reboot of Win7, the value always gets reset to 8.

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent this registry key from getting reset on reboot.  For some "tweaks" like this, there will be a corresponding key within `Wow6432Node` in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive that also needs to be changed, but after my research, I didn't find any reason to suggest that is true in this case.

---

Note: The *comments* below [this article](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-number-of-recent-items-to-display-in-windows-7-jump-lists/) describe the same issue as I describe above (the article itself is regarding a related, but different, topic).

Comment: Try also setting in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` the DWORD item of `Start_JumpListItems` (create if missing).